# Travel to Hong Kong (Indian citizen) with passport having less than 6 months validity

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, hong-kong

One of my Indian friends has to travel to Hong Kong from India urgently. His passport has less than 6 months validity and he does not have enough time to renew his passport (he has to fly tonight).

Indians only need a permit to visit Hong Kong, which has to be applied online and that's exactly the problem for my friend: he can't apply for it as the system throws an error because the passport has less than 6 months validity.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[The HK Immigration website](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html) is quite clear:

> (a) holds an Indian passport valid for at least six months;

Your friend won't be able to fly to HK, at least not until the passport has been renewed.

Comment: yeah, I also read that. I thought maybe someone can suggest some way (maybe by some application/letter etc.)

Comment: HK is not the kind of place with grey areas. And, especially, when it comes to immigration.